# Error "Msg 10054, level 20, State 0, Line 0" with MSSQL under Docker

Tags: sql-server, docker

I've set up several docker containers in my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS machine. All of them have in common the same [container image](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/mssql-server-linux/).

It works pretty well, but some users have reported me a common issue when attempting a long-lasting query and about a minute after it execution, they get an error message:

> Mens. 10054, Nivel 20, Estado 0, Línea 0
>   Error en el nivel del transporte al recibir los resultados del servidor. 
>   (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - Se ha forzado la interrupción de una conexión existente por el host remoto.)

The error message is translated into english as `Error 10054, level 20, State 0, Line 0`.

Is there something I can modify under their configuration?

PS: I've noticed that in server's properties Connection > Remote servers connections > I've "Permitir conexiones remotas con este servidor checked", having 0 seconds (no wait time) of waittime.

*EDIT*
I attach one container's configuration snapshots:
[image: General configuration]
[image: Memory configuration]
[image: Processors' configuration]
[image: Connections' configuration]
[image: Database configuration. Current values omitted (they're the same).]
[image: Advanced configuration]

Omitted the permission config, as I don't think it's relevant.

Comment: The [remote connections configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-remote-access-server-configuration-option) is not relevant. Check the SQL Server error log for related server messages.

Comment: I haven't found any error on `/var/opt/mssql/log/errorlog`...

Comment: Any success solving this problem? I'm having the same.

Comment: Nope... The logs say anything related to the error... Wouldn't it be that I shouldn't be deploying production databases in a docker container?

Comment: I'm still having the issue

Comment: Are users connecting via SSMS or a third party application?

Comment: Users are connecting using SMSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the issue by making use of the oficial [MSSQL image from Microsoft](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/mssql-server-linux), as I was using a custom Ubuntu 16.04 LTS + MSSQL packages. All the data was stored within a volume, so the transition from one container to the new was easy.

EDIT:
The previous didn't actually solve the problem. The real issue was that I was querying too much data. Querying an extensive dataset implied a huge RAM consumption, as much as it was permitted. I wasn't limiting it at all, so when reached the maximum amount of RAM available, the OS (dispatcher) would kill the process. The solution has resulted to configure a memory limit.